# Using Multiprocessing concurrency mechanisms in Celery tasks

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery

I am trying to interface with a device which can only accept a single TCP connection (memory constraints) and so just starting a connection for every worker thread is not an option as it is with a normal client-server situation such as a database connection.

I have tried using a Multiprocessing Manager dict that is globally accessible between threads, in the format of:

`clients{(address, port): (connection_obj, multiprocessing.Manager.RLock)}`

And a task like this one:

```
from celery import shared_task
from .celery import manager, clients

@shared_task
def send_command(controller, commandname, args):
    """Send a command to the controller."""
    # Create client connection if one does not exist.
    conn = None
    addr, port = controller
    if controller not in clients:
        conn = Client(addr, port)
        conn.connect()
        lock = manager.RLock()
        clients[controller] = (conn, lock,)
        print("New controller connection to %s:%s" % (addr, port,))
    else:
        conn, lock = clients[controller]

    try:
        f = getattr(conn, commandname) # See if connection.commandname() exists.
    except Exception:
        raise Exception("command: %s not known." % (commandname))

    with lock:
        res = f(*args)
        return res
```

However the task would fail with serialization errors such as:

`_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_thread.lock'>: attribute lookup lock on _thread failed`

Even though I am not calling the task with a non-serializable value and the task does not try to return a non-serializable value Celery seems obsessed with trying to serialize this global object?

What am I missing? How would you go about making client device connections used in Celery tasks threadsafe and accessible between threads? Example code?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for your situation, but I just remembered reading about `multiprocessing.reduction`, which should allow for sharing of socket connections between processes.  [See this blog post for an example](http://foobarnbaz.com/2011/08/30/developing-scalable-services-with-python/).

Comment: The client isn't working with a raw socket, it is a Twisted connection object which has a protocol. Using a raw socket or reconsituting a Twisted connection object from a fd is non-trivial.

Comment: I ended up working out how to wrap a Twisted protocol around an existing socket, however it would not work in my case because Celery consumers as *separate child processes* of the worker main process could not access the File Descriptors needed (stored in Redis), and setting up the tangle of unix pipes to share the FDs is too much hackery.
 
The problem with my situation is the device is memory constrained and simply cannot just have multiple connections... So I have decided to just have  a pool of workers with a single consumer and one device each. Not nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
 ...
self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_thread.lock'>: attribute lookup lock on _thread failed
```

After looking around the internet I realised I had probably missed something important in the traceback. After looking at the traceback closer I realised that it was not Celery trying to pickle the connection object but rather Multiprocessing.reduction. Reduction is used to serialise on one side and reconstitute on the other.

I have a few alternative approaches to work around this problem - however none of them really do what I originally wanted which is to just borrow the Client library connection object and use it, which just isn't possible with Multiprocessing and prefork.

Comment: Ah, I guess my answer was a bit a hasty since you want to pass around the same connection object.  Mutliprocessing and prefork don't usually play nice with connections and i/o between processes.  You usually want to establish a connection post-fork.  Have you considered switching from prefork to eventlet or gevent for concurrency, and then implementing a connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing a distributed lock manager using Redis?  The Redis python client has lock functionality built-in.  Also, see [this doc](http://redis.io/topics/distlock) on redis.io.  Even if you're using RabbitMQ or another broker, Redis is very lightweight.

For example, as a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def device_lock(block=True):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return_value = None
            have_lock = False
            lock = redisconn.lock('locks.device', timeout=2, sleep=0.01)
            try:
                have_lock = lock.acquire(blocking=block)
                if have_lock:
                    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                if have_lock:
                    lock.release()
            return return_value
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@shared_task
@device_lock
def send_command(controller, commandname, args):
    """Send a command to the controller."""
    ...
```

You can also use [this approach](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html) from the Celery task cookbook:

```
from celery import task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from django.core.cache import cache
from hashlib import md5
from djangofeeds.models import Feed

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 5 # Lock expires in 5 minutes

@task(bind=True)
def import_feed(self, feed_url):
    # The cache key consists of the task name and the MD5 digest
    # of the feed URL.
    feed_url_hexdigest = md5(feed_url).hexdigest()
    lock_id = '{0}-lock-{1}'.format(self.name, feed_url_hexdigest)

    # cache.add fails if the key already exists
    acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(lock_id, 'true', LOCK_EXPIRE)
    # memcache delete is very slow, but we have to use it to take
    # advantage of using add() for atomic locking
    release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(lock_id)

    logger.debug('Importing feed: %s', feed_url)
    if acquire_lock():
        try:
            feed = Feed.objects.import_feed(feed_url)
        finally:
            release_lock()
        return feed.url

    logger.debug(
        'Feed %s is already being imported by another worker', feed_url)
```

Comment: I am was aware of these solutions - however the reason I have not used it is because it does not do what I wanted which is to just share the actual connection object between processes and use the already open connection. I am trying to avoid disconnecting and reconnecting every time a task is run. 

I can keep the connection object as a global if I run the worker with a single thread and reuse it. I am considering just using a pool of single-process workers for these clients. Else if I do choose to just connect every time I message then I will do locking using Redis. Among other solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use gevent or eventlet celery worker instead of processes and threads? In this case you will be able to use global var or threading.local() to share connection object.

Comment: I was getting lock-ups using eventlet. I could try harder to find out why but there is little incentive because of the blocking IO nature of what I am trying to do is unsuitable for the event-loop nature of eventlet/gevent.